# How to add a overload to MVCs Authorize Attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, authorization

I have used `[Authorize]` attribute a lot in the past, and it allows you to also do things like this:

```
[Authorize(Users = "test")]
```

However, I would like to add another one,

```
[Authorize(IsPermitted= PermissionsEnum.ThePermission)]
```

I have the logic written out that would decide if the user was permitted for that permission, but I'm not sure how to add that overload to the authorize attribute.

I would prefer not to make a entirely separate authorize attribute if possible.

Comment: Even if you could "overload" or extend existing Authorize Attribute, how much would you save yourself? You still have to overwrite the authorizecore to change the logic...

Answer (score 2):

Well, as @Dave A has said on the comments, you can extend the native `Authorize` attribute and implement your own authorization method, for sample:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    // create your custom property
    public PermissionsEnum IsPermitted { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool authorized = // create your own validation and return a bool value                
        if (authorized)
        {
            return false;       
        }

            // if you want to have the nativa validation, call it from the base method
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

and remember to decorate your controllers/actions with your Custom Authorize Attribute, for sample:

```
[MyAuthorize(IsPermitted = PermissionsEnum.Sales)]
public class OrderController : Controller 
{
   // actions...    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not. The only possible properties that you can set are
Users and Roles. So you have to make a separate Attribute class.